# Dynamically move an item from one list to another in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, templates

I'm trying to create a simple interface for a recipe app where there is a list of ingredients and when an ingredient is clicked, it moves from the "Ingredient" column to the "Meal Ingredients" column. I'm trying to do this in a simple way of just clicking a button, the ingredient, and moving it to a different column. I'm new to JavaScript, JQuery, and AJAX, so I'm not quite sure how to piece it together, but this is what I have so far in a template:

```
{% block title %}Home{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1>Create a Meal</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h3>Ingredients</h3>
          <div class="text-left">
            <ul>
              {% for ingredient in ingredients %}
                <div class="row">
                  <button id="btnName" class="btn my-1">{{ ingredient.name }}</button>
                </div>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h3>Current Meal</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="text-center">
            <h4>Meal Ingredients</h4>
            <div class="text-left">
            <ul class="justList">
            </ul>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="text-center">
            <h4>Amount(g)</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <script>
    $('#btnName').click(function(){
      var text = 'test';
      if(text.length){
          $('<li />', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.justList')
      }
    });
  </script>
{% endblock content %}
```

I'm able to add the "test" string to the new list, but I can't remove it. I also want to just dynamically add the ingredient button so when the user clicks it again, it will go back to the other list. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably update the `{% for %}` loop in your template so that the buttons do not all have the same `id`. [This is invalid HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), as `id`s should be unique.

Then, you could attach the event listener to the `.btn` class (or some other selector corresponding to the button):

- When the button is clicked, get the name of the ingredient from the button's `innerHTML`.
- Loop over the existing ingredient list.
- If that ingredient does **not** exist in the list, add it.
- If that ingredient does exist in the list, remove it.

Below is an example derived from your code (run the snippet to see it in action). If you click the ingredient button once, it adds that ingredient to the list. If you click it again, it removes that ingredient from the list.

See also the inline comments I added to the code. Obviously in your case, you wouldn't have these "hard-coded" ingredients. Instead, they'd be populated by Django. But for this example I just created some sample ingredients.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  var text = this.innerHTML; // the ingredient

  var itemFound = false; // flag to indicate if the ingredient already exists in the list
  $('ul.justList li').each(function() { // loop through the existing list of ingredients
    if ($(this).text() === text) { // if the ingredient already exists, change itemFound to true
      itemFound = true;
    }
  });


  if (!itemFound) { // check if itemFound flag is false (item doesn't exist in the list yet)
    $('<li/>', {
      html: text
    }).appendTo('ul.justList') // if the item doesn't already exist, add it
  } else { // if it does, remove it
    $(`ul.justList li:contains(${text})`).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1>Create a Meal</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h3>Ingredients</h3>
        <div class="text-left">
          <ul>
            <div class="row">
              <button class="btn my-1">Milk</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <button class="btn my-1">Sugar</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <button class="btn my-1">Flour</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <button class="btn my-1">Eggs</button>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h3>Current Meal</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="text-center">
            <h4>Meal Ingredients</h4>
            <div class="text-left">
              <ul class="justList">
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="text-center">
            <h4>Amount(g)</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Evan_Bloemer any luck with this?